# Checking if a text contains words from a txt file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, text

My goal is to check if whatever I type in text box matches any of the words of my list. My list is in a `.txt` file. I figured I should convert the `.txt` into an array and maybe compare its values to another array, which is the one that comes from the textbox (form). I assumed I should bring the text from the `.txt` file into an array, but that comparison is not quite working.

It could be something like:

```
$count = 0;
If ($textbox contains $anyofthewordsfromthe.txt file)
 echo "Name of the words:" $numberofocurrences.
Else
  echo "No words from the list!"
```

Thank you! Happy Holidays!

Comment: how many words are on your text file???

Comment: Do Google your question's title. You're bound to find something, I am 100% certain of it.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code that you have tried and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in online or copy the code from the page

http://www.wordcounter.net/

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the comparison?
You can put the words in an array, and then make the comparison with in_array()

Answer (score 0):

First load the list of words as an array, using `file_get_contents()` followed by either `explode()` or `preg_match_all()`. Then check to see if each word in the message is in the list or vice versa. You can look for each word in the message using `strpos()`, which will find "thorpe" if "Scunthorpe" is in the message. Or you can break the message into words too and look for each word in the list, which will ignore spurious substrings. The following command-line PHP script shows both approaches:

```
<?php

// Like explode() but uses any sequence of spaces as delimiter.
// Equivalent to Python s.split()
function explode_space($s) {
  preg_match_all('/[^\s]+/', $s, $words);
  return $words[0];
}

$swears_filename = 'words.txt';

// Load all words from the file
$swears = strtolower(file_get_contents($swears_filename));
$swears = explode_space($swears);

// In a web environment, it'd probably be more like this:
// $naughty_text = trim(@$_POST['comment']);
$naughty_text = 'I tweeted about passing the third rep milestone on Stack Overflow.';

// Perform case-insensitive comparison by lowercasing everything first.
$naughty_text = strtolower($naughty_text);

// There are two solutions. The first uses substring matching,
// which finds "thorpe" in "Scunthorpe" if "thorpe" is in words.txt.
foreach ($swears as $swear) {
  if (strpos($naughty_text, $swear) !== false) {
    echo "Text contains substring $swear\n";
  }
}

// The other solution will find "Scunthorpe" only if "scunthorpe"
// itself is in words.txt because it checks the whole word.
// First convert the list of values to a set of keys to speed up
// testing whether each word is in the set because
// array_key_exists($k, $array), which looks for keys, is
// faster than in_array($v, $array), which looks for values.
$swears = array_fill_keys($swears, true);

// Now convert the post to a list of distinct words.
$naughty_text = explode_space($naughty_text);

foreach ($naughty_text as $word) {
  if (array_key_exists($word, $swears)) {
    echo "Text contains word $word\n";
  }
}
```

When I run this (apologies to the late George Carlin):

```
$ cat words.txt
slit pass puck cult locksacker monkeyfighter hits part third tweet
$ php so27629576.php
Text contains substring pass
Text contains substring third
Text contains substring tweet
Text contains word third
```